# What is purpose of QnARequestContext.previousUserQuery in QnA Maker Options for Generate Answer API (QnA Maker)?

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I was following code sample about QnA Maker [multiturn](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/70.qnamaker-multiturn-sample/dialogs/qnamakerMultiturnDialog.js) feature. If I want to use that I have to fill `QnAMakerOptions.context` in request for Generate Answer API. Its type is `QnARequestContext` and this interface specifies 2 fields: `previousQnAId` and `previousUserQuery`.

In that code sample only `previousQnAId` is filled which makes sense for me because for context only follow up questions QnA Maker needs to know what was the previous question. But what is purpose of `previousUserQuery` and why should I use that?

I was trying to understand it from API documentation but I was unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find any documentation to back this up, but my best guess for purpose of the `previousUserQuery` is to provide a sane, human-readable alternative to the `previousQnAId` property for debugging. This provides context around how an answer was arrived at.

There is an example response from the QnA Maker API that includes the `previousQnA*` properties available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/multiturn-conversation#a-json-request-to-return-a-non-initial-answer-and-follow-up-prompts):

```
{
  "question": "Use Windows Hello to sign in",
  "top": 10,
  "userId": "Default",
  "isTest": false,
  "qnaId": 17,
  "context": {
    "previousQnAId": 15,
    "previousUserQuery": "accounts and signing in"
  }
}
```